# Better way to get and show list of items in a page(JSON vs HTML)

Tags: javascript, html, json, ajax

I am getting a list of items in a JSON(through AJAX) and creating the required markup by JS and appending in the view. On the other hand I have seen few examples which do not use this practice, and send the complete or partially complete markup through AJAX and then simply append them to the document. So definitely the markup is being generated on the server.

**So I am curious which one is the better approach and why**. One thing I can clearly see is that the later approach does not expose the JSON structure to the UI.

Comment: *"the later approach does not expose the JSON structure to the UI"* - But that's not particularly important is it? The JSON would only need to contain the same data the user will eventually see, so it's not exactly a secret.

Answer (score 0):

You're right about exposing the json structure but perhaps the main thing to consider is loading times, both client side and server side. If the server is dedicated and powerful enough, generating the markup in the server will be fast and will keep the site snappy on the client side.
If not, you'll want the client to do as much of the processing as possible. Generating markup on the client side is not a bad thing. The popukar angularjs framework builds markup on the fly client side and is very effective.

Comment: Conversely JSON may (probably will) take up less bandwidth than the corresponding HTML would.

Comment: True. All depends on how much bandwidth and processing power the client and server has.

Answer (score 0):

The choice depends on several factors like

- `what we are trying to achieve` - Requirement must be picture clear.
- `what is the amount of work involved with these choices alone`
- `which choice will have better performance`
- and in few scenarios `which choice will get the job done quick`. - where performance is compromised over delivery

Lets take an example to explain better.

> 1) Create a table to display all the details of employee.

Here since this is a stand alone table we don't have to worry about passing a JSON and then writing logic inside the JS to build the table. This can be done quickly without the need of JS. -- **HTML Wins**

> 2) Create a table to display all the details of employee. Also build a dynamic bar graph to display the details of the employee group on click of any row in the table.

Here the scenario is to build a table also on click of any table row get the employee group and generate a bar graph to show total employees in that group or may be any other stuff.

Here if we have built out table with just HTML then to get the data for the bar graph either we need to make another server call OR do a for loop of all tr's and then extract data from each cell by cell which is a pain.

If you use JSON to dynamically build the table structure, We can use the same JSON data and then build the graph and quick without other overhead, As we have the data ready to manipulate. -- **JSON wins**

---

This is just a small example. Also this concept is totally debatable, it is choice of the developer and what he is comfortable with, along with few other factors as mentioned above. I think you get the big picture. Hope this is helpful.